# Get vuejs component name in a v-if

Tags: templates, vuejs2, vue-component

Is it possible to get the name of the component within it's own v-if statement?

```
   <StartActionPlan
      v-on:proceed="newActionPlanWizardState($event)"
      v-if="isCurrentWizardState('--component-name--')}">
   </StartActionPlan>
```

I want to implement a multistep wizard and want to get the name in order to decide whether to show a wizard step. For this purpose I'd like to compare the name of a component with the current step in a wizard without having to explicitely use the name of the component.

Comment: Why couldn't you just keep name as data property?

Comment: I think a good solution would be using some kind of state in this wizard that you can use for your v-if's logic.